# How to reload .emacs.d/ configuration without restart

Tags: init-file, configuration-files

When I change any custom configuration file in the `.emacs.d/elisp/` directory, I have to quit Emacs and then start it again in order to get my changes applied. Is there any better way?

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EvaluatingExpressions and https://masteringemacs.org/article/evaluating-elisp-emacs and `M-x load-file` are all good to know.  Note that, depending on the code in question, re-evaluating something isn't necessarily the same as if you had started Emacs with the code in that state to begin with.

Comment: @phils thanks for the links. Yes, that's the problem, "reevaluation isn't always the same as to start over". Is there any way to flush the state and apply configuration?

Comment: No there isn't.  On a case-by-case basis one can generally determine how to revert specific things, but the only "flush state" option is restarting Emacs (because the "state" in Emacs is everything -- configuration, code, data, buffers, etc; it is all intertwined).

Comment: If you have a specific example at hand, you could post a new question asking how to deal with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you have changed you configuration in a `.el` file, just reload it with `M-x eval-buffer` command. Or use the menu `Emacs-Lisp->Evaluate buffer`.